# correct way to load data async in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await

**What is the correct way to load data async to be able to show UI as fast as possible to user.** For example

I have a xamarin forms projekt, containing a map component. 
I want to show the map before I get the users current location(from gps) and some locations/pins that are fetched from a server. I have seen these two approaches

1) From constructor call an async method

```
   Map mMyMap;
   ctor()
   {
       InitializeCompeont();
       InitAsync();
   }
   private async void InitAsync()
   { 
      var pins = await GetPinsFromServer();
      mMyMap.Pins.Add(pins)
   }
```

2) in On appearing

```
 ctor()
  {
   InitalizeComponent()
  }
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
  { 
      var pins = await GetPinsFromServer();
       mMyMap.Pins.Add(pins)
   }
```

Both approaces seems to "work", but Im I fooling myself calling the async method from constructor?

Ive also managed to set BindingContext async both ways and it binds correctly

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a difference in timing and when your load data will be called. If done in the page `ctor` it will be called once and only once when that page is first created.

If done in `OnAppearing` the call will happen prior to the page being shown and can be called more than once. For example, if you push another page on top of it and then popped it `OnAppearing` would get called again reloading your data, which might be okay to do if that other page modified the data being displayed on the previous page. Otherwise, you're potentially making unnecessary load data calls.

It is worth noting that `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` aren't always consistently called at the same time on different platforms. For example, if you used the built-in sharing on Android or iOS one might fire both events, but the other might not fire any at all.

Also, I'd make sure you're making use of `Task.Run();` to run any long running tasks on a background thread, to ensure you're not locking up the main thread, and potentially set a bool to show/hide a spinner if necessary to know when your background task starts and ends.

Comment: Hi Nick! Thanks for your answer. Ok that clearifies how I should use it. I have a question about the last part though. (Task.Run()...). I Thought my UI-thread was released on await (and I have verified it by looping 50 times (to enlongate time to fetch my map pins and can see that map loads seconds before pins shows up on it)). Are you saying that "await MyLengthyGet()" is not enough to release UI-thread?

Comment: I haven't seen your `GetPinsFromServer ` implementation but typically as long as you're using async await all the way throughout your methods and not using a `.Result` or `.Wait` anywhere you're usually fine. What I meant by using `Task.Run` is your method sounds like it could potentially be a long-running task in which case you might consider running it in the background with a `CancellationToken` because async await itself doesn't necessarily create a new thread and you may want to stop the task depending on what the user does.

Comment: yes, Im using async await all the way, with out Result.. I think I have to read up on  the differnce ... thanks for your help!