# Can someone clarify where I should put code when with the MVVM pattern when fetching data for a screen?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application screen that when navigated to shows words on a screen one after another. Between showing each word the app waits a period of time.

The functionality currently is like this:

```
Page Constructor (xaml.cs)
   vm = new CardsTabViewModel();
   BindingContext = vm;

Page OnAppearing
   Loop
      Get first word into variable x
         vm.Word = x.Text
             Wait a few seconds
   End Loop
```

I am trying to implement MVVM but am confused about where the code should be that gets the data.

Should the code that gets the data be in the OnAppearing of the page and if not where should it be?

Comment: It depends if you only need it to load once I'd do it in the Page ctor. If you put it in `OnAppearing` your code will get called every time you come back to the page like if you pushed a new one on top then hit back. If you want a more detailed explanation you can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476029/correct-way-to-load-data-async-in-xamarin-forms/52481634#52481634).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an `Init` method in your VM that does whatever is needed.  Then call it from either your page constructor (if it only needs to be called once) or `OnAppearing` (if it needs to be called every time the page is displayed)