# Xamarin.Forms - Page crashes app with System.Reflection.TargetInvoicationException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use Microcharts to display a piechart from some `List<ChartEntry>`. I have a method in a different class called `DrawSummaryPieChartAsync()` to generate that list. When I click on the particular `page` it fires the associated `viewmodel`. The problem is that the method is an asynchronous task and so it needs to be awaited. Which means I can't declare it in the constructor of the viewmodel. I have tried many workarounds here on SO but I can't seem to figure how to make them work in my case. So I proceeded to follow the spirit of this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60804577/xamarin-asynchronous-data-binding)

> VisualDataPage.xaml

```xml
<microcharts:ChartView HeightRequest="300" Chart="{Binding ExpenditurePieChart}"/>
```

> VisualDataPage.xaml.cs

```cs
    public partial class VisualDataPage : ContentPage
    {
        public VisualDataPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new VisualDataViewModel();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            (BindingContext as VisualDataViewModel).GetPieChartCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
```

> VisualDataViewModel.cs

```cs
    public class VisualDataViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<ChartEntry> _chartEntries;
        public static IChartDraw ChartDraw => DependencyService.Get<IChartDraw>();
        public ICommand GetPieChartCommand { get; }

        public VisualDataViewModel()
        {
            _chartEntries = new List<ChartEntry>();
            GetPieChartCommand = new Command(GetPieChart);
        }

        private async void GetPieChart()
        {
            _chartEntries = await ChartDraw.DrawSummaryPieChartAsync();
        }

        public Chart ExpenditurePieChart => new PieChart
        {
            Entries = _chartEntries
        };

    }
```

It crashes with this inner exception of a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`:

> `Method not found: void UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer..ctor()`

When I set breakpoints, it stops just after this block below finishes executing

```cs
private async void GetPieChart()
{
    _chartEntries = await ChartDraw.DrawSummaryPieChartAsync();
}
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Check if linking is enabled, and disable it. That's not a correct fix, but at least will narrow down something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. I got the clue from this github issue [here](https://github.com/microcharts-dotnet/Microcharts/issues/35#issuecomment-347827539). It had to do with compiling to iOS. I simply added

```cs
_ = new Microcharts.Forms.ChartView();
```

to the `FinishedLaunching` method of `AppDelegate.cs`. If you have a clue as to why this works, let me know.

```cs
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            _ = new ChartView();

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
```

So while I got to know that this error had nothing to do with me trying to initialize an asynchronous method in the constructor, my approach was also wrong. So I'll also provide what I did to solve that problem below as well for anyone who might come across this problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476029/correct-way-to-load-data-async-in-xamarin-forms) SO post helped me solve this part

```cs
    public class VisualDataViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<ChartEntry> _chartEntries;
        public static IChartDraw ChartDraw => DependencyService.Get<IChartDraw>();
        public ICommand GetPieChartCommand { get; }

        public VisualDataViewModel()
        {
            _chartEntries = new List<ChartEntry>();
            InitAsync();
        }

        private async void InitAsync()
        {
            _chartEntries = await ChartDraw.DrawSummaryPieChartAsync();
        }


        public Chart ExpenditurePieChart => new PieChart
        {
            Entries = _chartEntries
        };
```